# External User for JFrog Artifactory Pro sees "Build Browser"

Tags: artifactory

I want to share few of our libraries with our customers using JFrog Artifactory Pro. I have added a User for the customer and set permission to only show those packages which we want to share. However, when I login into JFrog Artifactory using the newly created (restricted) user I can see

1. Artifacts - Which only shows what I want to expose
2. Builds - Which shows all the projects which are built?

Is there any way to disable Build Browser for certain users?

If my expectations here are wrong or I am way off mark, please take a moment to explain what is the industry standard.

My basic aim is to use jfrog artifactory to expose certain artifacts in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 0):

In Artifactory you can block the access to the builds tab only for users that are not signed in. In case that a user is logged in and has read permissions on a repository then he will be able to see the builds tab. There is an open feature request for adding permissions to the builds tab. You can vote and watch this feature [here](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-4398).